# Why are there so many waveguide feeds (?) near the focus of Cassini's dish antenna?

Tags: radio-communication, cassini, radar

Cassini has quite a complex [Radio Science Subsystem](https://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/radio-science-subsystem/). Accorting to that article (and confirmed in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini%E2%80%93Huygens#Description)):

> Cassini is the only deep space mission to transmit to Earth at three radio wavelengths (approximately 14 cm wavelength, designated S-band; 4 cm, designated X-band; and 1 cm, designated Ka-band) simultaneously.

That says "simultaneously", quite a dish-full.

But there are also a bunch of non-axially located rectangular-waveguide-like objects that are also near the focus of the high-gain antenna system. What are these things for, and are they actually pointed towards the secondary mirror and using it for collimation? I am wondering if this gives some spatial resolution like a giant compound-eye of an insect.

**below x2:** Screen shots from the animated/simulated part of the montage video [Video file: Saturn Plunge Nears for NASA Cassini Spacecraft](https://youtu.be/Lie5-rTcCmk) found on the apparently official [JPLraw](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYt2JN2z3ZXQpgPHt_eKcTw) YouTube channel. The video contains a variety of Cassini-related material, images, and interviews.

[image: Cassini multiple waveguide feeds]

[image: Cassini multiple waveguide feeds and low-gain antenna]

[image: Cassini 2]

**above:** "A diagram of the Cassini spacecraft and Huygens probe." From [here](http://www.latimes.com/science/la-sci-cassini-oral-history-20170912-htmlstory.html). NASA Jet Propulsion Laboratory. *Open in a new window for full size so you can see the detail and read the descriptions!*

**below:** From Handbook of Reflector Antennas and Feed Systems Volume III: Applications of... edited by Sudhakar Rao, Lotfollah Shafai , Satish K. Sharma, screenshot from google books:

[image]

Comment: Speculation, but that looks to me like a beam-forming array so they can transmit off the boresight of the antenna.

Comment: @Tristan beam-forming is usually done with an array that's not also at the focal plane of an also-beam-forming Cassegrain reflector. This is optically more like a focal plane array - the Cassegrain system would form a different beam for each waveguide output. But that's just a working hypothesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of those are the Ku-band antenna feeds for the Radar. The high-gain antenna also serves (served) as part of the Radar science instrument. The HGA was pointed at Titan many times to get synthetic-aperture radar images of the surface of Titan, otherwise obscured by the haze in the atmosphere to visible light instruments.

[image: lots of feeds]
[image: image of HGA]

Comment: Buh bye Cassini, my first spacecraft. Sniff.

Comment: The *real photo* is much appreciated, thanks. I'm still scratching my head on the "Why are there so many..." part. Are these 20 or so rectangular windows mostly emitters, or receivers, or a mix of both? Are there so many in order to get some angular segmentation, as in a focal plane array? You may want to take a few days and reply later, the timing is awkward I know.

Comment: There are four look angles to the side and one on center for the radar. There are five horns for each of the four side look angles.

Comment: I've accepted the answer and I'll go off and do some more reading. I'm still having trouble understanding why five feed horns are used for a given look angle. Usually when using multiple phased emitters to produce a beam, they are in free space and not at the focal point of an imaging system.